# index of a /sqrt is complex and produces error

Tags: sqrt

I want to write in latex and an error occurs,
if you could help me please
[image]

```
 \[
 F=\left(\sqrt[\sqrt[\sqrt{7}]{7}]{\sqrt[7]{7}^{7^{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}}}}\right)^7
 \]
```

Comment: Is there any reason, apart from academic interest, to write such an unmathemathical thing?

Comment: @egreg Isn't the $n$-th root usually only defined for natural numbers $n$?

Comment: @CampanIgnis There is nothing that prevents defining it for any nonzero real, but it is really awful, IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra set of braces `{..}` around the optional argument in the outermost `\sqrt` command.

`\sqrt[{\sqrt[\sqrt{7}]{7}}]{\sqrt[7]{7}^{7^{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}}}}`

But the spacing looks bad to me, so I would use `\Biggl(` and `\Biggr)` instead of `\left` and `\right`, and also use `\raisebox` with a negative argument to lower the expression inside the parentheses.

Also, it looks like you are missing a set of braces after `\sqrt[7]{7}^{..}` inside the main radical.

```
 \[
 F=\Biggl(
 \raisebox{-1.4ex}{$\hspace{-.7em}\sqrt[{\sqrt[\sqrt{7}]{7}}]{{{\sqrt[7]{7}}^7}^{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}}}$}
 \Biggr)^{\!7}
\]
```

[image]

But then the last exponent inside the main radical looks low to me, so you could use another `\raisebox`. Also the 7 outside the main radical looks too small. So...

```
\[
 F=\Biggl(
 \raisebox{-1.4ex}{$\hspace{-.7em}\sqrt[{\sqrt[\sqrt{7}]{\scriptstyle7}}]{{{\sqrt[7]{7}}^7}^{\raisebox{.7ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}$}}}$}
 \Biggr)^{\!7}
\]
```

Which will produce the image

[image]

Of course you can adjust the spacing however you like.

Answer (score 5):

The `amsmath` package provides the macros `\leftroot` and `\uproot` to fine-tune the position of the optional argument of `\sqrt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \leftroot and \uproot macros
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[
F=\left(\!\!\!
\sqrt[\uproot{-4}{\sqrt[\uproot{4}\leftroot{-1}\sqrt{7}]{7}}]
{{{\sqrt[\leftroot{1}\uproot{2}7]{7}}^7}^{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}}}\,
\right)^{\!7}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Mostly stealing this, from Mico. The vertical imbalance in the parentheses looks bad, so let's use an array. Usually an array is used for horizontal alignment, but we want its minor feature of vertical centering without forcing the width like a `\parbox` would. Use `@{}` entries to adjust horizontal spacing instead of `\!\!\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \leftroot and \uproot macros
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[
F=\left(
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{-5pt}}l@{\hspace{2pt}}}
\sqrt[\uproot{-4}{\sqrt[\uproot{4}\leftroot{-1}\sqrt{7}]{7}}]
{{{\sqrt[\leftroot{1}\uproot{2}7]{7}}^7}^{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}}}
\end{array}
\right)^{\!7}
\]
\end{document}
```

There is some ambiguity still from the formatting of the root-7 over 7 exponent.

[image]

Comment: +1. Much better-looking than my solution is.